# how to disable Intellij string evaluation

Tags: string, validation, intellij-idea

How or where can I disable in Intellij Idea the string validation feature?
If I write a string, it will be checked like this:
[undesired behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4I46.png)
I would like it to appear like a normal string, like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDs7q.png)
Can this be done somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [Language Injection](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/language-injections.html) feature of IntelliJ. To disable it completely you can remove *IntelliLang* plugin in *Settings/Plugins*.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is the setting you're looking for:

[image]